# Why can I not style a Textarea in CSS?

Tags: html, css, resize, textarea, styling

I am trying to change the color of my textarea and disable re-sizing, but nothing will change  when I save the CSS file. I have made sure that there are no errors in my code, and I had someone else try the same line of code on their computer, and it worked. Here is the code:

HTML -

```
<textarea rows="30" cols="50">Test</textarea>
```

CSS -

```
textarea { 
    resize: none;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: it could be anything without a page to see in which the issue occurs

Comment: Caching issue perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

So, I am an idiot. I had been linking the wrong CSS file, because I had two with very similar file names. My God, I feel stupid

Answer (score 0):

Edit: LOL xD

```css
textarea {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<textarea rows="30" cols="50">LOL</textarea>
```